# ExtJS - xtype 'breadcrumb': change items and style in selectboxes and in breadcrumb text list

Tags: extjs, breadcrumbs

I have a directory (folder) structure, which I show with the xtype 'breadcrumb' (ExtJS Version 6.6).

Now I will add a additional toggle in my app. When I active the toggle, all folders should be shown in the breadcrump text list and in the selectboxes. This is my actual developing status and works fine.

When I deactive the toggle, all folders with a leading "A" in the folder name should be hide in the selectboxes (or should be disable and shown grayed out). In the breadcrump text list this ("A"-)folders should be shown grayed out.

For example I have the breadcrump text list "root > folder_0_0 > folder_1_0" in my app and then I change the toggle value: Then I do not want to reload the complete breadcrump.

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you for your hints Thomas

here is my code. You can find this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mqb

```
    Ext.application({
        name: 'BeadcrumbTest',
        launch: function() {
            var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                root: {
                expanded: true,
                    text: 'Root_folder',
                    children: [{
                        text: 'A_folder',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'B_folder',
                        expanded: true,
                        children: [{
                            text: 'A_folder',
                            leaf: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'B_folder',
                            leaf: true
                        }]
                    }, {
                        text: 'C_folder',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }
            }),
                panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    width: 400,
                    height: 100,
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    tbar: {
                        xtype: 'breadcrumb',
                        store: store
                    },
                    buttons: ['->', {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Handle "A" folder',
                        handler: function() {
                          // todo
                        }
                    }]
                });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I overwrite the methods updateSelection(), _onMenuClick() and _onMenuBeforeShow() from classic/src/Breadcrumb.js.